# C# Windows Form searching specific value in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a form with a combobox. I'm reading a file and with info in the file I need to pre-populate this combobox.
Example:
Combobox is populated like so:

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Letters");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("One");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Two");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("AB", "Alpha Bravo");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("BC", "Bravo Charlie");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("CD", "Charlie Delta");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("DE", "Delta Echo");
        cbLetters.DataSource = dataTable;
        cbLetters.DisplayMember = "Two";
        cbLetters.ValueMember = "One";
        cbLetters.SelectedItem = 1;
        cbLetters.Refresh();
```

When I search like this: cbLetters.SelectedValue = FieldFromFile.ToString(); I don't retrieve any records. And the FieldFromFile is filled with "CD". I also tried cbLetters.SelectedValue = FieldFromFile.

When I search like this: cbLetters.SelectedValue = "CD"; I retrieve Charlie Delta as expected.

It's killing me. Needless to say I'm new to C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: But when I use cbLetters.SelectedValue = "CD" I do get what I'm looking for. Then how do I search using a variable? I've tried many ideas I've found, but none seem to be working for my case. I can't believe nobody has done something similar.

Comment: Where is the code for `FieldFromFile`?

Comment: @Brian - that is a field that comes from the file I'm reading. It's a string, filled with 2 characters.

Comment: A literal "CD" and string variable with the value "CD" are for the purposes of this question identical.  There's something you aren't showing us that is problematic.  Show the variable initialization code please.

Comment: The layout of the file is: Name string, Letters string, Score int. I use the field "Letters" for the lookup.  I've tried to create a string in the program (string searchLetter = "";) and use that field, but that didn't work either.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  Please post the rest of the related code.

Comment: @Brian. We just had them re-send the file. It works now. Not sure what happened. The data looked good in the first file and it seems identical to the second file. One of my co-workers suggests that maybe the data in the first file got screwed up. So sorry to have wasted your time. Your initial "A literal "CD" and string variable with the value "CD" are for the purposes of this question identical" was correct.

Comment: Garbled data will do it.  Could be a bad upload, had that issue with FTP before.  If needed, you could run an MD5 hash compare of the two files to see if they come out identical.  Nice text editors should show hidden characters as well.

Comment: @Brian. They snuck an extra space in it. When I trimmed the field in the first file, it worked. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not getting the value, the problem is the set datasource , note the ComboBox is not contains elements. Eg:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Letters");
dataTable.Columns.Add("One");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Two");
dataTable.Rows.Add("AB", "Alpha Bravo");
dataTable.Rows.Add("BC", "Bravo Charlie");
dataTable.Rows.Add("CD", "Charlie Delta");
dataTable.Rows.Add("DE", "Delta Echo");
var cbLetters = new ComboBox();
cbLetters.DataSource = dataTable.DataSet;
cbLetters.DisplayMember = "Two";
cbLetters.ValueMember = "One";
cbLetters.Refresh();
var foo = cbLetters.Items.Count;
Console.Write(foo); //retun 0
```

Edit: The problem is your code not has any DataBind  "cbLetters.DataBind();",

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Letters");
dataTable.Columns.Add("One");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Two");
dataTable.Rows.Add("AB", "Alpha Bravo");
dataTable.Rows.Add("BC", "Bravo Charlie");
dataTable.Rows.Add("CD", "Charlie Delta");
dataTable.Rows.Add("DE", "Delta Echo");

var cbLetters = new DropDownList();
cbLetters.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
cbLetters.DataSource = new BindingSource(dataTable, null);
cbLetters.DataValueField = "one";
cbLetters.DataTextField = "two";
cbLetters.DataBind();  // Here DataBind  
cbLetters.SelectedIndex = 2;
//cbLetters.Refresh();
Console.Write("value selected -> " + cbLetters.SelectedValue); //return CD
Console.Write("text selected -> " + cbLetters.SelectedItem.Text); // return Charlie Delta
```